# How to create semi pie progress with highcharts?

Tags: javascript, highcharts, angular8

[semi-pie progress, what i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECkE7.png)

Hello guys. How can i implement this kind of semi-pie progress bar with highcharts?
I tried alot and my result show as below photo. i want to create dataLabels same as first photo. if there is any way, please let me know.
i use this code for datalables:

```
dataLabels: {
        formatter: function() {
            return this.y > 1 ? '<b>' + this.point.name + ': ' + this.y + '%</b>' : null;
        }
```

[my result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tf6MA.png)

Comment: I have a question - is this chart will have a fixed value or it should be dynamically? If it will be dynamically is this label should be moved around the pie?

Comment: definitely the value should be dynamically. yes it will be changed around the pie but should be vertical.

Answer (score 0):

So I created a guideline with custome functionality how to render a dataLabel which is 'attaching' to the pie point via using the SVGRenderer feature.

See code below and the demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/23ybcdjm/ and the version with path: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/u843xnoe/

```
chart: {
    events: {
      render() {
        let chart = this,
          series = chart.series[0],
          point1 = series.points[0],
          point2 = series.points[1],
          shape1 = point1.shapeArgs,
          shape2 = point2.shapeArgs,
          distance,
          distance2 = 50,
          PI = -Math.PI,
          label1,
          label2,
          x1,
          y1,
          x2,
          y2;

        //check if label exist while resize
        if (chart.label1) {
          chart.label1.destroy()
        }

        if (chart.label2) {
          chart.label2.destroy()
        }


        //set x and y positions for labels
        x1 = shape1.x + (shape1.r * Math.cos(shape1.end));
        y1 = shape1.y + (shape1.r * Math.sin(shape1.end));
        x2 = shape2.x + shape2.r + distance2;
        y2 = shape2.y + chart.plotTop;


        //render label1
        chart.label1 = chart.renderer.label('Actual: ' + point1.y, x1, y1)
          .css({
            color: '#FFFFFF'
          })
          .attr({
            fill: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75)',
            padding: 8,
            zIndex: 6,
          })
          .add();

        //render label2
        chart.label2 = chart.renderer.label('Target: ' + point2.y, x2, y2)
          .css({
            color: '#FFFFFF'
          })
          .attr({
            fill: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75)',
            padding: 8,
            zIndex: 6,
          })
          .add();

        //find distance for label which is moving around the pie
        if (shape1.end > PI && shape1.end <= 0.55 * PI) {
          distance = -chart.label2.getBBox().width
        } else if (shape1.end > 0.55 * PI && shape1.end <= 0.45 * PI) {
          distance = -chart.label2.getBBox().width / 2
        } else if (shape1.end > 0.5 * PI && shape1.end < 0.25 * PI) {
          distance = chart.label2.getBBox().width / 3
        } else if (shape1.end > 0.25 * PI && shape1.end <= 0) {
          distance = chart.label2.getBBox().width / 2
        }

        label1 = chart.label1;
        label2 = chart.label2;

        //translate labels
        label1.translate(label1.x + distance + chart.plotLeft, label1.y)
        chart.label2.translate(chart.label2.x, chart.label2.y - chart.label2.getBBox().height)          
      }
    }
  },
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.render

API: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#label

Comment: First of all Thanks Sebastian Wędzel.
your code is perfect, but need some changes, if it is possible:
1- 99.7 as target is the end point that we want to achieve.
2- this is a kind of progress bar, so no need to calculate percentage.
3- also the second link has some problem if you change your screen size.
4- your series are 'Actual' and 'Target'.
Thanks again for replying soon.

Comment: 1 and 2. - I added a function which will render the data - https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/w2u4e57g/ 3. - https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/dtovp6wc/